# How can I convert single quotation mark to double and double to single with python str.replace?

Tags: python, string

example string:

```
strr = "{'a':5}"
```

expected output:

```
'{"a":5}'
```

I tried these and got the same string

```
strr.replace('"',"'")
strr.replace("'",'"')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `strr.replace("'",'"')` should work (`print(strr.replace("'",'"'))`. Strings are immutable, so `replace` returns a new string. It doesn't modify the string inplace

Comment: The replace builtin string function returns another string. It does not modify the string (strr) as Python strings are immutable

Comment: Also, there are no double quotes in your string. Think about it

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> strr
"{'a':5}"

>>> for r in (('"','\''),('\'','"')):
...   s = strr.replace(*r)
... 

>>> s
'{"a":5}'
```

Comment: This only looks right because of the way the interactive Python shell shows strings. Try it in a script and you'll see the problem. Or, consider what would happen to this string:- "\"{'a':5}\""

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you write a string lets say strr = "Hi there", your str will be Hi there, without the quotes, so making a string like ""Hi there"" seems imposible (i tried but maybe im wrong).
But you can build a string like "'Hi there'", so you want to do

```py
strr = "{'a':5}"
#save the value because str.replace is a non void function
newstring = strr.replace("'",'"') # {"a":5}
```

Comment: You can write such a string like `'"Hi there"'` or `"\"Hi there\""`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap literal double-quote for single-quote and vice versa then:

```
strr = "\"{'a':5}\""
s = ''.join("'" if s == '"' else '"' if s == "'" else s for s in strr)
print(s)
```

...will result in:-

'{"a":5}'